# Repositioning of Tab Bar Issues

Tags: swift, uitabbar

For the app that I am making, I am using two tab bars, one at the bottom of the screen and one under the navigation bar at the top of the screen.  After repositioning the tab bar to the top, when I run the app there is a black rectangle where it would be if not repositioned.  How do I get rid of this black box?

[image]

Here is the code that moves the tab bar:

```
import UIKit

class tabControllerDistrict: UITabBarController {
    @IBOutlet var bar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.bar.frame = CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you would like to use a tab bar for the top one? I'd go with only one tab bar on the bottom and use a stack view with buttons for the top one.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

Two things.. first your frame is incorrect.  The y value must be 64, because that is the height of the Navigation Bar.  Your tool bar would appear behind it if you set it to 0.

Secondly, setting the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is incorrect.  According to Apple:

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method.

You aren't changing the superview, so no need to call this function.

Simply set the frame of the bar in `viewDidLoad()` and it will work perfectly.